# swift 3 - search result also with diacritics

Tags: swift, search, swift3

In my application I use a search that works well but I need advice. I do not know how to do that when I search for text without diacritics that the result also with diacritics. **Example:** Enter a search holesovice, I need to find **holesovice** and also **holešovice**.

**Here is part of my code:**

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        filteredERequests = requests.filter({( request : CityRequest) -> Bool in

            return request.cityName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

        })
        myTable.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `range(of:, options:)` with options for a diacritic insensitive
(and optionally case insensitive) search. Example:

```
let list = ["holesovice", "holešovice"]
let searchTerm = "sovi"

let filtered = list.filter {
    $0.range(of: searchTerm, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
}

print(filtered) // ["holesovice", "holešovice"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but honestly I do not understand, how to use it in my code... :(

Comment: @Alien: And I cannot compile your code because it is not self-contained :) – But it should be something like `return request.cityName.range(of: searchText, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil` in your closure.

Comment: I am donkey :D. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is Martin R's solution, just easier to consume.

Copy this into a Swift file:

```
extension String {
    func contains(insensitive other: String, range: Range<String.Index>? = nil, locale: Locale? = nil) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: other, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive], range: range, locale: locale) != nil
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if "Música".contains(insensitive: "music") {
    print("hurray!")
}
```