# Translate UITextField input text into Spanish runtime

Tags: ios, wordpress, swift3, translate

An iOS app which displaying wordpress blogs. There is search feature, App searches world-phress into API's data. Wordpress website contents are in Spanish language.

My issue is when user inputted text "Buho", app should search "Búho", "Buho", "buho", "búho" in Spanish data and display result according. Curretnly app is matching word "buho", not "búho".

On Wordpress website, same thing is possible, User can search either "Búho" or "Buho", all search result displayed.

How to translate UITextField's text value into Spanish, So I can easily search into NSArray and show result. Or is it possible to replace character set?

Simple english word searching is possible using NSArray filter, search into blog's title and text with particular text.

Like this:

```
let searchingWorld = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
let blogSearchResult = self.blogs.filter{ $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchingWorld) || $0.text.lowercased().contains(searchingWorld) || $0.tags.contains(searchingWorld) || $0.categories.contains(searchingWorld) }
```

self.blogs object is array of dictionary type object. {title, text, category, tags}
Not found any solution.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Punita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're not looking to translate to Spanish, but are looking how to do a so called [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) insensitive search.

iOS has a [search option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412313-diacriticinsensitive) to do that.

In the same way you can specify an [option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412382-caseinsensitive) to do a case insensitive search.

[Here're is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41823393/1971013) that I hope helps.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I want. You have saved my lots of time. Thank you very much sir!